# Adapt Method for Multiple Object Types?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have this method which lets me translate the position of an object, animating its move in my iPhone app:

```
-(void)translatePositionForLabel:(UILabel *)label toFrame:(CGRect)newFrame
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    label.frame = newFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

You can see this works for `UILabels`, but without having a duplicate of this method (just swapping the object for say `UIButton`) is there anyway I can adapt this method so I can pass any object with a frame? Rather than needing an individual method for each object type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `UILabel` and `UIButton` have a common ancestor in `UIView`; try passing that in place of `label` (you only appear to modify the label's `frame` property, which is defined in `UIView`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a category for `UIView` with methods for moving with animation:

**UIView+Additions.h**

```
@interface UIView (Additions)

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame animated:(BOOL)animated;

- (void)translateToPoint:(CGPoint)point animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

**UIView+Additions.m**

```
@implementation UIView (Additions)

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)newFrame animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    self.frame = newFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)translateToPoint:(CGPoint)point animated:(BOOL)animated {
    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.origin = point;
    [self setFrame:newFrame animated:animated];
}

@end
```

Now you can just call `[button setFrame:newFrame animated:YES]` or `[label setFrame:newFrame animated:YES]`.